# Time Breaking in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a fun challenge with some time data in my application. I have a table of start and end times; and need to subtract out shift times keeping the difference to get multiple rows. Im trying to do this on my SQL Server 2008 box at the moment.

The idea is if i have a time row like

```
Start 09:00 End 19:12
```

And the shift says 09:00 -> 17:00 I need to split / break the data into two rows

```
Start 09:00 End 17:00
Start 17:00 End 19:12
```

This needs to work over midnight too; created some scratch data as I have been playing around with some ideas but am wondering if there is a way out of case statement heck.

```
Create Table dbo.tblClockEvents
(
DayOfWeek Int,
ClockOn Time,
ClockOff Time
)

Create Table dbo.tblShiftPattern
(
DayOfWeek Int,
StartTime Time,
EndTime Time
)

insert into dbo.tblShiftPattern
select 1, '07:30', '17:00'
union select 2, '09:30', '18:00'
union select 3, '09:30', '18:00'
union select 4, '09:30', '18:00'
union select 5, '20:30', '04:00'


insert into dbo.tblClockEvents
select 1, '07:30', '17:00'
union select 2, '09:22', '18:14'
union select 3, '09:12', '18:01'
union select 4, '09:22', '18:14'
union select 5, '20:22', '04:14'

Select * 
from dbo.tblClockEvents aa
inner join tblShiftPattern bb
on  aa.DayOfWeek = bb.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT aa.*,bb.StartTime,bb.EndTime
  FROM dbo.tblClockEvents aa
  INNER JOIN tblShiftPattern bb
  ON  aa.DayOfWeek = bb.DayOfWeek
 )
SELECT DayOfWeek,ClockOn as [start],
CASE WHEN EndTime > ClockOff THEN ClockOff ELSE EndTime END AS [end]
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT DayOfWeek,EndTime,ClockOff
FROM cte
WHERE ClockOff>EndTime
ORDER BY 1,3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3d87/8)

Comment: @rs. thank you. It's should be order by 1,3. I updated answer